# how do I convert the elements of a list to integers?

Tags: python

I'm doing beginner python IO stuff, and I have to import a file. In the file there are a bunch of dates and and the year, month and day are separated by commas. I've split them but need them to be integers, how would I do that? I've tried a few different things but they all say "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4076.79\n'"

```
salesFile = "Sales.txt"

try:
    inpFile = open(salesFile, "r")
except:
    print "error"
else:
    startYear = 2001 
    startMonth = 1 
    startDay = 1 
    endYear = 2001 
    endMonth = 2 
    endDay = 1 
    print startYear, startMonth, startDay
    print endYear, endMonth, endDay
    validItem = True
    while validItem == True:
        line = inpFile.readline()
        if line == "":
            validItem = False
        word = line.split(",")
        numWords = len(word)
        for idx in range(numWords):
            temp = word[idx]
            temp = int(temp)
            word[idx] = temp
```

Comment: The code causing the error you cite is not in the snippet you posted here.

Comment: You can't be getting this error as there are even no calls to `int`...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: number `'4076.79\n'` is not integer but real so you can't conver with `int(4076.79\n')` - you can convert to float `float(4076.79\n')` and later round to `4076` using `int()` - `int(float('4076.79\n'))`

Comment: ah yes, just changed it, that is now what I tried last.

Comment: ok it works now! thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

If you have `t='12904\n'`, make sure to put `t=t.strip()` to remove whitespace on the edges.

Also if you expect non-integer inputs, use `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: @furas Oh I see, he was trying to convert a string representation of a float to an int